# select database by user who logged in, in odoo

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-15

I have multiple users and same number of databases. A unique database for each user.

I want to select database dynamically whenever user login with his details. I don't want him to select or input his database name in any form. The selection should be automatic and without user knowledge.

One way to do it is using `db_filter` .
see here https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/dbfilter.html

We can use different subdomain for each user and then database can be selected by subdomain name.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: How about using multi-website instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the database by URL's param

For example:

http://localhost:8069/web/login?db=your-database-name